# How to apply CSS width to a submit input on Firefox?

Tags: css

I applied the same width to an anchor and a submit input. The anchor looks right, but the submit input's width is too small. The problem occurs only in Firefox. Chrome is fine.

**Browser**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<a>Save</a>
<input type="submit" value="save" />
```

**CSS**

```
a,
input {
   display: block;
   width: 5em;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 1.4em;
   padding: 0.6em 2em;

   /* hack to get the width to work on Chrome */
   box-sizing: content-box; 
}
```

Comment: Try `padding: 0.6em;`, if I get your point right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try inline-block instead of block

```
a,
input {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 5em;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 1.4em;
   padding: 0.6em 2em;
}
```

Comment: Does not work. Plus, I can't use pixel dimensions. A) It doesn't scale with the parent. B) It ignores the user's browser font-size setting.

Comment: @JoJo you have to change padding to px as well in order to make it work. Leave em for font-size as user11... suggested (so did I in my answer)

Comment: `display:inline-block` fixes it and allows me to continue using `em`. I have no idea why. Just some voodoo programming.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same effect in Chrome. I'm not sure why, but it looks like the padding-right is not getting applied to the input element. How you should solve this depends on your specific case, which I don't know enough about to answer. Hopefully knowing the immediate cause of the issue will be enough.

**Edit**
See the OP's comment on this post for his solution. All that's needed to make it work in FF is `-moz-border-box: content-box`

Comment: I updated my code. `box-sizing: content-box;` will make it work in Chrome, but doesn't fix Firefox.

Comment: Nice find. It's not working in FF because FF hasn't implemented box-sizing without its browser prefix yet. In other words, just add `-moz-border-box: content-box` to your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a CSS reset, It looks like the default width/padding of each of these elements is coming into play here.

a, input { width:0; padding: 0; margin: 0;}

Comment: I am using Yahoo's YUI reset, which contains those rules. I chose not to copy and paste my entire CSS because it's too much to read.

Comment: Okay. I'm fiddling it now and I see what you mean. It could be that the anchor has a text node inside it ('Save') while the input element has the text as an attribute. I wonder if the padding, width and other styling properties are being applied differently to the text node and the attribute node.

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is that you use `em` for dimensions like width or for padding.
There are a lot of articles why it is encouraged to use `em` for font-size, however you should not really use them for size, padding, margin etc. If you want to make your layout 'flexible', use `%` instead. Otheriwse stick to `px`.

Comment: em VS px is unrelated to my problem. Changing to px dimensions doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @JoJo are you sure you changed it in the padding as well? or did you mean that such solution is not an option ?

Comment: At first, I tried only changing width to px. That didn't help. Then I changed padding to px also. The anchor and submit input now look nearly the same, but not exactly.

Comment: add margin: 0px and chances are they will be the same. Oh, and remove this hack : )